# How can I tie Google Play Billing subscriptions to specific accounts?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

My app has user accounts.  Users can create an account, login, and consume content.

I'm interested in creating a subscription model for certain content and using Google Play Billing as a medium for processing those subscriptions.

However, [it appears subscriptions are tied to the Google account being used on the device](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases).  This makes sense.  However, if one of my users logs into their account (my platform) and purchases a subscription, I don't want a different user (my platform) to be able to log in on that device and have access to subscribed content.  That is a different user from my perspective.

I'm guessing my backend will need to store purchase tokens and tie them to accounts (my platform).  When the app loads and checks for subscriptions (or when a new user logs in), it will hit the `getPurchases()` method and pass the result + currently logged in account (my platform) to the backend for access confirmation?  Would this break any rules regarding allowing users access to content that was subscribed to on the device?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution to this problem? I am unable to make purchases from the second user account as I get a response saying that I have already bought this item. And that's probably because both in app accounts are using the same underlying Google Play account. Please let me know if you've found a workaround for this. Would really appreciate it!